# Merge [aggregate] and [aggregates] into [aggregate-functions]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

Tags [aggregate](/questions/tagged/aggregate) (646 questions) and [aggregate-functions](/questions/tagged/aggregate-functions) (777 questions) have basically the same wiki. The latter is specifically about SQL, while the former is more generic, but both are being mostly used on questions about SQL. There's also [aggregates](/questions/tagged/aggregates) (19 questions), that doesn't have a tag wiki.

I'm suggesting merging [aggregate](/questions/tagged/aggregate) and [aggregates](/questions/tagged/aggregates) into [aggregate-functions](/questions/tagged/aggregate-functions). I tried to suggest synonyms, but I don't have enough score on any of those tags, and a merge seems more appropriate anyway.

### UPDATE

I believe other people are not seeing there is a problem with these tags. Unlike what kiamlaluno said on his answer, [aggregate](/questions/tagged/aggregate) is *not* "a more generic tag about aggregating data". At least, that's not what its wiki says (this is the full wiki; emphasis is mine):

> An aggregate, **more commonly known as an aggregate function**, is a means to examine the values found in multiple rows from a single column. These are grouped together as input on certain criteria to form a single value of more significant meaning or measurement, such as a set, a bag or a list. Aggregates are usually found in [SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info).

**So, I'm okay if you disagree about merging the tags, but if we don't do that, shouldn't we at least redefine [aggregate](/questions/tagged/aggregate) and completely rewrite its wiki?**

Comment: As you mention, aggregate can be a generic term. It can be applicable across many languages and/or technologies. For example, you can aggregate in LINQ. I think it would be bad to merge these tags.

Comment: I don't see why questions about LINQ aggregation should have a separate tag. What about questions about aggregation using ORM frameworks? It's all fundamentally the same, the tag wiki could be more generic if the tags were merged. Maybe the tag to be kept would be [tag:aggregates], or perhaps [tag:aggregation], to encompass all those use cases (including NoSQL DBs).

Comment: 3/4 of the [tag:aggregate] functions are not about SQL. The tag wiki describes only 1/4 of the usage of the tag. [tag:aggregate] should definitely not be merged into [tag:aggregate-functions] since that would make about 450 questions mistagged. I don't have a clear picture of all the things [tag:aggregate] means. It may be too vague to stand, in which case it should be split into several tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that re-writing the [aggregate](/questions/tagged/aggregate) tag to be a more generic "aggregating data" tag is a good solution. (But I oppose merging [aggregate](/questions/tagged/aggregate) into a SQL specific tag.)

SQL is far from being the only tool used to aggregate data. 21 of the first 100 questions with the [aggregate](/questions/tagged/aggregate) tag come from the R statistical programming language and have basically nothing to do with SQL. (As an aside, there is actually a very common *function* in R called `aggregate`.)

Frankly, it makes more sense to me not to have any "aggregate"-like tag be specifically tied to a particular language. No language owns that concept, so it makes more sense to me to have one [aggregate](/questions/tagged/aggregate) tag and then if you want to specify what language you're in you'd just add that other tag as well. Otherwise you end up in the mess we're in now. But that may be too radical of a change, given the number of questions involved.

That said, if I ruled the universe, I would re-write the wiki for [aggregate](/questions/tagged/aggregate) to be more generic, and then merge [aggregates](/questions/tagged/aggregates) and [aggregate-functions](/questions/tagged/aggregate-functions) into it, while making sure that the [aggregate-functions](/questions/tagged/aggregate-functions) *also* have the relevant language tag for that question.

**Edit** Here's a quick stab at what the wiki for [aggregate](/questions/tagged/aggregate) might say:

Aggregate refers to the process of summarizing grouped data. Typically this involves replacing groups of data with single values (e.g. sum, mean, standard deviation, etc.).

Comment: That makes sense! I just suggested an edit on the wiki for [tag:aggregate] based on your suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

As slugster wrote, [aggregate-functions](/questions/tagged/aggregate-functions) is used specifically for SQL aggregate functions, and that is reflected in its tag wiki. It is also used in some [Mongodb questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aggregate-functions+mongodb), even though [Mongodb](http://www.mongodb.org/) is defined as a NoSQL database.
Differently, [aggregate](/questions/tagged/aggregate) is a more generic tag about aggregating data.

It makes sense to merge [aggregate](/questions/tagged/aggregate), and [aggregates](/questions/tagged/aggregates). Generally, in those cases, the plural form is kept.

Comment: Please see my update. [tag:aggregate] doesn't look so generic as it currently stands.